# StructureMap and Injection dependency "on the fly"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, structuremap

I am following this excellent [article](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/02/10/how-to-use-ninject-to-inject-dependencies-into-asp.net-mvc.aspx) in order to create my own attribute in the mvc.net framework v2 .
The Author , Simone Chiaretta, uses Ninject to inject dependency within an ActionFilter using the attribute [Inject] over the dependencies he has in his class.

I would like to know if the same kind of technics might be used with structuremap.

I hope to have given enough details, if not please ask.. ;)

yours,

UPDATE 1:

Here is some code to enlighten a bit my problem

```
public class GreetingAttribute :
ActionFilterAttribute,
ISuperActionFilter,IGreetingAttribute
{
    **[Inject]**
    public IGestioneUtenti _service { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        _service.Elenca();
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        ViewResult result = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
        _service.Elenca();

        if (result != null)
        {
            result.ViewData["Title"] += " - " ;
        }
    }
}
```

I would have loved to be able to have this [Inject] attribute. So that my InvokeActionMethodWithFilters would have looked like this :

```
protected override ActionExecutedContext InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(
    ControllerContext controllerContext, IList<IActionFilter> filters,
    ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary<string, object> parameters) 
{
    foreach (IActionFilter actionFilter in filters)
    {
        ISuperActionFilter superActionFilter = 
            actionFilter as ISuperActionFilter;
        if (superActionFilter != null)
        {
            ObjectFactory.DoInjectionForMarkedAttribute(actionFilter);
        }

    }
    return base.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(
        controllerContext, filters, actionDescriptor, parameters); 
}
```

Below my final implementation in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SetterProperty attribute is equivalent to Ninject's Inject.

Also, take a look at this blog post: http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2008/10/09/setter-injection-in-structuremap-2-5/ for more details on setter injection in Structuremap.  Unfortunately Some of the examples use an older syntax , but all the ideas apply.

Comment: I don't think this will work with attributes that are instantiated by reflection.  Have you tested it?

Comment: I never said using SetterProperty by itself would make this work; the question was about an equivalent to Ninject's Inject.  You still need to override InvokeActionMethodWithFilters and call BuildUp, similar to the blog Post Yoann linked to.

Answer (score 2):

My final solution (well up to now, because week end is arriving so fast.. :):

> public class GreetingAttribute :
>   ActionFilterAttribute,
>   ISuperActionFilter,IGreetingAttribute
>       {
>           **[SetterProperty]**
>           **public IMyService _service { get; set; }**
>
> ```
>     public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext
> ```
>
> filterContext)
>           {
>               _service.Elenca();
>               base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
>           }
>
> ```
>     public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext
> ```
>
> filterContext)
>           {
>               ViewResult result = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
>               _service.Elenca();
>
> ```
>         if (result != null)
>         {
>             result.ViewData["Title"] += " - " ;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

and the StructureMapControllerActionInvoker:

> public class
>   StructureMapControllerActionInvoker :
>   ControllerActionInvoker
>       {
>
> ```
>     public StructureMapControllerActionInvoker()
>     {
>     }
>
>     protected override ActionExecutedContext InvokeActionMethodWithFilters( ...)
>     {
>         foreach (IActionFilter actionFilter in filters)
>         {
>             **ObjectFactory.Container.BuildUp(actionFilter);**
>         }
>         return base.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(
>             controllerContext, filters, actionDescriptor,
> ```
>
> parameters);
>           }
>       }

thanks for all your help

Comment: An advice - use actual Action Filters separately - as separate classes, MVC3 allows for that. And Attributes to only, well, mark filters as attributes. Resolve your Filters with their dependencies inside those attributes (use some sort of Service Locator). Shortly: use your attribute to only call actual Filter. All the actual work should be done in Filter, not FilterAttribute.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use `ObjectFactory.GetInstance<WhatYouWant>()`

It is the StructureMap equivalent to Ninject's `KernelContainer.Kernel.Get<WhatYouWant>()` like in the article you posted.

You can't make extension methods to `ObjectFactory` because it is a static class.  If you look at th article you will see that the `NinjectControllerActionInvoker` accepts an `IKernel` in the constructor.

Similarly, you can receive an `IServiceProvider` implementation that wraps `ObjectFactory` in your constructor.  For example:

```
public class StructureMapServiceProvider: IServiceProvider
{
    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return ObjectFactory.GetInstance(serviceType);
    }

    public T GetService<T>()
    {
        return ObjectFactory.GetInstance<T>();
    }
}
```

Then, from within your `StructureMapActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters` , you can write

```
 if(actionFilter is ISuperActionFilter){
        var propertiesToInject = 
            GetType()
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Select(p => new{ 
                InjectAttribute = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(InjectAttribute),true).FirstOrDefault(),
                PropertyInfo = p}
                )
                .Where(x=> x.InjectAttribute != null);
        foreach(var syringe in propertiesToInject)
        {
            syringe.PropertyInfo.SetValue(actionFilter, _serviceProvider.GetService(syringe.PropertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
        }
 }
```

..You're welcome

Comment: I am updating my question to reflect my problem

Comment: @Yoann, Everything you read in that article can be done with StructureMap.  If you don't want to make the static call to ObjectFactory, then you can create an IServiceProvider wrapper and inject it into a StructureMapActionInvoker just like the NinjectActionInvoker does with an IKernel.  I don't understand what else you want.

Comment: I am not so clever, so I just need some more details or some more time to think about what you wrote ;)

Comment: @Yoann, updated the answer...  It should set you on the right track

Comment: Thx SmartCaveman for your input. Your solution is far more advanced from what I would have been able to do on my own. Have a nice week end.